# Looping over set of columns to perform spearman correlation analysis

Tags: r, loops, correlation

I am interested in doing a spearmen correlation test where I determine if the data in the first column (`x`) is negatively correlated with any of the 2,314 remaining entries in in my table.

The input I am using seems fine when I manually input the details to compare `x` against `y` , for example:

```
data<-read.table("input.txt",header=TRUE)
x=data[,1]
y=data[,2]
cor.test(x,y,method="s")
```

.. However, when I apply a `for` loop to iterate over all 2314 columns it (1) doesn't work but also (2) gives me no errors.

```
data<-read.table("input.txt",header=TRUE)
x=data[,1]
y=data[,2:2314]
for (i in y){
cor.test(x,i,method="s")
}
```

Here is short example of my data:

```
GeneData    Test_Gene   Gene1   Gene2   Gene3   Gene4
Day1    429.92  5948.10 49.09   7965.23 1367.21
Day2    273.64  6394.40 66.39   4858.45 1529.97
Day3    2505.83 3384.90 45.99   5881.83 906.59
Day4    1290.60 3364.54 48.15   5754.26 894.16
```

I would like to see if "Test_Gene" correlates with any of the remaining samples (Gene1,Gene2, Gene3 or Gene4).

Comment: IMHO you `for` loop is wrong. Try something like `for (i in 2:ncol(y)) { cor.test(x, y[,i], method="s") }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply`:

```
x <- data[1]
lapply(data[-1], cor, x = x, method = "spearman")
```

To do a `cor.test`, you have to use double brackets to extract the first column as a numeric vector (not as a one-column data frame):

```
x <- data[[1]]
lapply(data[-1], cor.test, x = x, method = "spearman")
```

Comment: I tried this method and it works for performing a cor analysis but when i try to do a cor.test i get the following error:                 Error in cor.test.default(X[[1L]], ...) : 
                       'x' and 'y' must have the same length. I am interested in performing a cor.test analysis as i also require p-values. If you have any thoughts on how to work around this it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you don't do anything with the results of `cor.test`. You either need to assign it to something with `<-` or `print` it.

```
x=data[,1]
y=data[,2:2314]

corr.values <- vector("list", 2313)
for (i in 1:length(y) ){
            corr.values[[i]] <- cor.test(x, y[[i]], method="s")
            }
head(corr.values)
```

Comment: Hi, so i tried this method and got the following error message "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)". I then expanded this error message which revealed "In corr.values[i] <- cor.test(x, i, method = "s") :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". Do you have any suggestions on how i could go about fixing this?

Comment: Try the modified code. If you had included a test dataset of say 4-5 columns, you would have gotten better answers.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your help thus far. The modified code outputs no errors, however, it only outputs the results for 6 comparison.. which i thought was quite odd as there is no obvious reason from the code on why it would cease at 6. Is there something i am overlooking? I have also included a sample of my dataset in my original question as you have recommended.

Comment: Cannot tell. If there are only 6 columns, you get six results. You appear to be testing a character column, "GeneData", against a numeric column, but maybe you used different numbers?